# Kohana 3.1 create imagejpeg or imagepng captcha

Tags: captcha, kohana-3

Im trying to put a simple captcha in kohana 3.1 using the following code to generate for me the image from a model.
        $session = Session::instance();

```
                            $string = '';

                            for ($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) {
                                $string .= chr(rand(97, 122));
                            }

                            $cns_captcha = $session->set('random_number', $string);

                            $dir = LIBPATH.'fonts/';

                            $image = imagecreatetruecolor(165, 50);

                            // random number 1 or 2
                            $num = rand(1,2);
                            if($num==1)
                            {
                                $font = "Capture it 2.ttf"; // font style
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                $font = "Molot.otf";// font style
                            }
                            // random number 1 or 2
                            $num2 = rand(1,2);
                            if($num2==1)
                            {
                                $color = imagecolorallocate($image, 113, 193, 217);// color
                            }

                            else
                            {
                                $color = imagecolorallocate($image, 163, 197, 82);// color
                            }


                            $white = imagecolorallocate($image, 255, 255, 255); // background color white
                            imagefilledrectangle($image,0,0,399,99,$white);

                            imagettftext ($image, 30, 0, 10, 40, $color, $dir.$font, $cns_captcha);

                            //header('Content-Type: image/PNG');
                            imagepng($image);
```

unfortunately this is producing 
�PNG  IHDR�2�*�v�IDATx���o�d���4��4oM�Ѵe�&�)�F��NCCB���� � q�i�� qp��6M�0�S�/����]����ͱ�C�4t��؎�D��d�y��_?�����G�x�À��
and no image 
thanks in advance for your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

You dont set the content type, your browser assumes it is text.

```
imagettftext ($image, 30, 0, 10, 40, $color, $dir.$font, $cns_captcha);

$this->response->headers('Content-Type', 'image/png');

imagepng($image);
```

EDIT:

as a sidenote, have you looked at Kohana's image module? http://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide-api/Image

Comment: This gives me an error ErrorException [ Notice ]: Undefined property: Model_captcha::$response. Im trying to look at the kohana image and see if there is something there i can use.

Comment: When i try using this example [link](http://forum.kohanaframework.org/discussion/6000/create-a-kohana-3-captcha/p1") . firefox tells me it cant display the image because it contains errors

Comment: Ah I was not aware your code was in a model. In that case 2 things: 1. Why does your Model output data? That is not MVC (let the model return the image object and let your controller echo it). 2. `Request::$initial->headers('Content-Type', 'image/png');` Also, take a look at my fork of some module, slightly modified for kohana 3.3.2 https://github.com/AmazingDreams/kohana-captcha it takes care of all the image rendering and you just have to care about where to put the HTML.